# How do I remove my Parrot MKI9200?

Tags: opel, electronics, bluetooth, agila

My Opel Agila has been replaced with one which is identical, but three years newer (2003). However, it has no Bluetooth, which is something I used a lot in my old car (2000)

Can I transfer the Parrot MKi9200 from the old car to the new car?

Can I just follow the installation instructions in reverse?

I really don't want to buy a new one for over £100, hence the question!

Comment: I don't know much about it, but it seems to be vehicle independent. If it was installed as an aftermarket device, there is no reason why it cannot be *uninstalled* from the old vehicle and installed on the new(er) one.

Comment: It's an aftermarket kit

Comment: If it doesn't matter to you, I'd suggest you *try* to remove it yourself and re-install it on the other car. It shouldn't be too difficult.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Note: I am from the UK, so if you are from other countries, your kit or the manual could be slightly different.**

So I did this over the weekend. It was a very difficult job, but I'm gonna write how I did it for reference. If you have back problems or anything, DO NOT attempt this job. I'm quite fit, and it made my back ache. Access is terrible, I also had a few cuts from the sharp metal radio holder.

Firstly, I got all the tools that I needed. These were:

- Some plastic spudgers from ebay. [These are the ones I bought](http://www.ebay.co.uk/sch/sis.html?_nkw=4x%20Auto%20Car%20Door%20Radio%20Clip%20Panel%20Trim%20Dash%20Audio%20Removal%20Installer%20Pry%20Tool%20UK&_id=381041370275&&_trksid=p2057872.m2749.l2658)
- Some philips and flathead screwdrivers
- Some kitchen knives ([that you eat with, not the sharp ones)](http://www.ecookshop.co.uk/ecookshop/products/large/xlarge/ZAIT0610.jpg)
- The **UK** Parrot MKi9200 [Instruction Manual](https://parrotcontact.parrot.com/website/user-guides/download-user-guides.php?pdf=mki9200/MKi9200_User-guide_UK.pdf), printed. This isn't very helpful, but it's useful to see how things go together, and how to pair the remote.
- A torch. I just used my phone.
- Some spanners if you disconnect the battery. I didn't bother when I installed it in my new 2003 Opel Agila.

This is what I did

1. I disconnected all the cables from the blue box which was simply held under the dashboard with cable ties.
2. I removed my **Sony** radio by sticking the knives in the sides, as I didn't have any removal keys.
3. I unplugged the antenna and the ISO adaptor at both ends, and pulled out the radio.
4. I then removed the microphone, and threaded it through the A-Pillar to remove it. I then unplugged the screen and removed it through the air vent. I had to remove the glovebox for this.
5. I then pulled all the wires through, and then cut the power wires before the inline fuse (I cut the off after though, as one was blown anyway)
6. For the power, the black wire is ground, the red wire is permanent live, and the orange wire is ignition live.
7. I then took the wires into the house and untangled them.

The job is really hard, as access is terrible. If you have small hands it's useful.